# Find SALT if password and hash are known

Tags: encryption, salt

I am a noob to security and I was wondering if it is possible to find the SALT if I know the password and hash?

Is there a function to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The salt is usually stored in front of the password hash. The salt must not be encrypted (it's used to spice the hash function which is used to check the password to prevent [rainbow table attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)). The size of the salt depends on the algorithm and its configuration. You need to check the actual implementation to see how many characters/bytes are used for the salt.

Comment: Note that salts are *often* stored at the front of password hashes, but there's no rule that this must true. Systems may store salts any way they want (such as in a separate database column), and may even compute their salt (while salts are ideally random and sparse, there are cases where it is much more convenient to use some unique value such as the user id as a salt).